# how to make a compiled android kernel file 'Image.gz-dtb' to a flashable .zip or .img file?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

My devices is **OnePlus3**.
   now I need to compile the kernel by myself and install it.
[I flow this to compile kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3/development/kernel-neweraelementalx-t3538241)

**log:**

```
SYSMAP  System.map
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15801_DVT/msm8996-v3-pmi8996-mtp_15801_DVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15801_PVT/msm8996-v3-pmi8996-mtp_15801_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT2/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT2.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT2/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT2.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT3/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT3.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT3/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT3.dtb
OBJCOPY arch/arm64/boot/Image
GZIP    arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT3/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT3.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT3/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT3.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15801_PVT/msm8996-v3-pmi8996-mtp_15801_PVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15801_DVT/msm8996-v3-pmi8996-mtp_15801_DVT.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT2/msm8996pro-pmi8996-mtp_15811_PVT2.dtb
DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/15811_PVT2/msm8996pro-v1.1-pmi8994-mtp_15811_PVT2.dtb
CAT     arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz-dtb
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC      drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/wlan.mod.o
LD [M]  drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/wlan.ko
```

How to flash the file **Image.gz-dtb** to the device ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Android Image Kitchen (https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) if you can get the factory boot.img file of your system. Simply run unpacking.bat on the boot.img and replace the boot.img-zImage file inside split_img folder with your new image.gz-dtb file. Then repackimg.bat will generate a new boot.img file for you.

Or using AnyKernel or AnyKernel2 to make a flashable zip file.